# Estimating average processing time based on complexity

Tags: regression, cross-section

We calculate average processing time (y) to monitor the efficiency of a process. The process can vary in complexity and we observe some proxies to assess the complexity of the process (x1, x2, x3).

Now, it has been argued that the complexity has increased over the last couple of years and that this is the reason for the increased processing time.  Hence, I was wondering, if there I a way to measure the processing time for a "standardized" process (controlling for x1,x2,x3).

My intuition was to set up a simple OLS estimation and include dummy variables for all but one year. I can then observe the sign of the year dummies and know whether it has increased or decreased over the years.

Now to be able to communicate this to the important people, I was wondering about the following two topics:

1. Is there a way to estimate the average time for a standardized process (controlling for x1,x2,x3)?
2. Since I will rerun the regression next year, this will of course produce different estimators and hence likely change the average time for a standardized process in all years. Is there a way to keep past averages fixed?
3. The time is not only influenced by the complexity, but also by the number of cases. How do I take this into account?

I assume that I am not the first person facing this problem, hence any pointers on where to look are very welcome.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Exchange :) I would like to help, but don't really understand your question. Bottomline: you want to see the effect of 3 covariates (X1; X2 and X3) on the average processing time (Y), what do you mean with the 'standardized process' that you want? If you have the feeling you 3 covariates changed, why not use these new ones in the model then? And if you want to see the difference in average time between the old complexity levels and new complexity levels, I think something like a t-test could also do the trick. I'm just not sure if I know what you seek ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer:
1) In a sense, I would like to answer the question, what would have been the average processing time in every year, if we were faced with the same mix of complexity in every year. Is this just the average value for t plus the coefficient of that year? 

2) If this true, I don't see a way to keep past averages constant. Because next year, I will benchmark it to the set of cases I observe next year. If I use the first year instead, the values will still change, because the coefficients of x1,x2,x3 are calculated based on all years, including the new year.

Comment: So, it is not the covariates that change, but the data to estimate the coefficients.

Comment: To see the average processing time every year, you can just calculate averages per year. To see the effect of the year (so how the average time changes every year), thats indeed done by regression with the variable year as covariate and while controlling on complexity gives you the interpretation: Year A will higher/lower the average time by  XXX compared to Year B, given the same mix of complexity. What do you mean 'keep the past averages constant'? What past averages do you mean? And how can the data 'change'? You observe your data, that data cannot change anymore right?